# Cabal doesn't update binary symlinks

Tags: haskell, osx-lion, cabal, cabal-install

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 with Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0. When updating packages with `cabal install`, the binary symlinks don't get updated to point to the new binary versions. I must delete the symlink manually and reinstall the package. `cabal install` says:

> Warning: could not create a symlink in
>   /Users/thsoft/Library/Haskell/bin for elm because the file exists
>   there already but is not managed by cabal. You can create a symlink
>   for this executable manually if you wish. The executable file has been
>   installed at
>   /Users/thsoft/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.4.1/lib/Elm-0.7/bin/elm

I tried using `sudo` and specifying `--symlink-bindir=/Users/thsoft/Library/Haskell/bin` explicitly, but none of them helped. How could I fix this?

Comment: Is there an answer to this one? I am having the same problem. Nothing from Cabal links.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the existing links that are present in the specified directory.

Comment: Meanwhile, the problem seems to have gone away by itself, but this might work anyway.

Comment: Didn't solve it for me. I've logged as issue here: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1802

Answer (score 1):

Tener's answer is correct: before 'cabal install'ing remove the links that would cause problems.  I've had the same problem and this solved it.

(I couldn't make this a comment to Tener's answer since that would require more reputation than I have. :-( )