# Cabal install criterion out of memory

Tags: haskell, memory, installation, cabal, haskell-criterion

I'm running on a container with 768MB ram and 512 MB swap space. I can't increase either of this. `cabal install criterion` always gives

```
Failed during the building phase.
The exception was: ExitFailure (-9)
This may be due to an out-of-memory condition.
```

during `Compiling Criterion.Types`. Is there any way around this or do I have to make do without criterion?

Comment: Try to set RTS flags on GHC to limit its memory usage (`--ghc-options="+RTS -M600M"`) and avoid running multiple jobs in parallel (`-j1`).

Comment: Thanks! If you write it as an answer I'll accept

Comment: Did it really work?!

Comment: Like a charm :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set RTS flags on GHC to limit its memory usage (`--ghc-options="+RTS -M600M"`) and avoid running multiple jobs in parallel (`-j1`).

Comment: This seems to get me further trying to cabal install cabal-install (trying to get from 2.4 to 3.4), but now throws this error: ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 8.6.5 for x86_64-unknown-linux):
 heap overflow

Comment: @marcel_g having the same issue when running this on an EC2 instance with 1GB of RAM. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DavidAzar - I did find a solution. I'll post my rough notes in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to @DavidAzar's comment on the answer:

@Li-yaoXia's solution worked, but then I had more problems. This is all from my rough notes as I tracked my way through the problem. So there might be a more streamlined solution.

Well, actually it compiled everything, but `cabal --version` still says 2.4, not 3.4. Maybe it's not in the path?

```
Warning: could not create a symlink in /root/.cabal/bin for cabal because 
the file exists there already but is not managed by cabal. You can create a symlink for 
this executable manually if you wish. The executable file has been installed at /root/.cabal/bin/cabal
```

There appears to be a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030330/52236
But I have to figure out how to remove the existing symlink before redoing the cabal install and doing the recompile process all over again.

There is also this solution here, which I will try first:
[updating cabal-install, but version is not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696529/updating-cabal-install-but-version-is-not-changed)

- Ran `unminimize` from bash, which installs all the normal stuff to ubuntu.
- First, in /bin, create a folder called /cabal-old, then copy the cabal executable to the cabal-old folder. Then remove cabal from the /bin folder.
- Then create a new symlink pointing to the new cabal executable:

  ln -s /root/.cabal/bin/cabal cabal
- This gets cabal 3.4 to show up when doing cabal --version.
- Next, install git: apt-get install git
- Then go to plutus-pioneer-program/code/week01/ folder and enter `cabal build`
- This downloads a lot of stuff from git, and then fails.

  Warning: Requested index-state 2021-02-24T00:00:00Z is newer than
  'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2021-02-23T23:53:53Z).
  Resolving dependencies...cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
  [__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
  [__1] trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.12.0.0 (dependency of Win32-network)
  [__2] next goal: plutus-pioneer-program-week01 (user goal)
  [__2] rejecting: plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0
  (conflict:base==4.12.0.0/installed-4.12.0.0, plutus-pioneer-program-week01 =>base^>=4.14.1.0)
  [__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, plutus-pioneer-program-week01)

  After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
  goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, Win32-network,plutus-pioneer-program-week01
- I got a suggestion from someone on Stackoverflow that the
  Plutus-Pioneer code might need ghc 8.10, and I'm on a version of
  8.6.5, so next step is to figure out how to update that.
- Before getting ghc 8.10, I apparently need to have ghcup installed,
  run this as non-root user?:

  curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
- this started the install, but failed because I don't have 'make' installed. Run this:

  apt-get install make
- then re-run the curl command. The curl installer output shows ghc 8.10 being installed, but after it's done, `ghc --version` outputs 8.6.5 still. Another symlink issue?
- I found this issue in the output:

  In order to run ghc and cabal, you need to adjust your PATH variable.
  You may want to source '/root/.ghcup/env' in your shell
  configuration to do so (e.g. ~/.bashrc).
- It also might require figuring out how to specify which version of ghc to use.
- I need to update the simlink in the bin folder in order to get the correct version of ghc being used, and there are the following other links to update:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Mar 24  2020 ghc -> ghc-8.6.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 226 Mar 24  2020 ghc-8.6.5  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Mar 24  2020 ghc-pkg -> ghc-pkg-8.6.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 258 Mar 24  2020 ghc-pkg-8.6.5  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Mar 24  2020 ghci -> ghci-8.6.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  55 Mar 24  2020 ghci-8.6.5
```

First, created a new symlink for ghcup:

```
ln -s /root/.ghcup/bin/ghcup ghcup
```

(Although I can't remember what I needed ghcup for.)

- Next, update the ghc symlinks for all 3 symlinks listed above in the /bin folder:

  mv -T ghc ghc-old-link
  ln -s /root/.ghcup/bin/ghc ghc
- This works to get the newer version of ghc showing up in the bash shell.
- Now trying to build, and it downloads and starts building a lot of stuff, but now this error happens:

  cabal: Failed to build cborg-0.2.4.0 (which is required by
  plutus-pioneer-program-week01-0.1.0.0). The build process was killed (i.e.SIGKILL).
  The typical reason for this is that there is not enough memory
  available (e.g. the OS killed a process using lots of memory).

Solution for this:
Docker -> Preferences -> Resources -> increase RAM, and swap space. In my case from 2-8GB RAM, and from 1 to 2 GB swap space.

Now it builds the Plutus Pioneer code for week 1.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Tried a few of these and made progress, but ultimately what fixed it was to get a bigger EC2 box. I tested a couple and ended up with a t2.xlarge with 16GB and had no problems. The software I was attempting to compile needed a more capable server to run on, but the documentation for it was out of date...

Comment: Yeah, I think what made the difference for me ultimately was @Li-yao Xi's solution plus increasing my Docker instances' RAM and swap space.