# cabal install ghc impossible happened: heap overflow

Tags: linux, docker, haskell, cabal, plutus

I'm trying to follow along with the Plutus Pioneer lectures, and I'm getting this error
My system:
Ubuntu Linux Docker image running on MacOS.
I installed the Haskell package on the image from here: https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html

using this line in my Dockerfile: `RUN apt-get install -y haskell-platform`

This seems to install Cabal version 2.4.

When I clone the code repository for the lectures: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program and then go to the week01 directory and try `cabal build` like in the lecture, I get dependencies not found errors. The first missing dependency is 'aeson', which seems to install if I run `cabal install aeson`.

The subsequent build attempts fail on dependency 'base' being the wrong version.

Then I thought maybe if I update Cabal to version 3.4 it might help, so I tried `cabal install cabal-install`, but this also has errors:

```
Theexception was:ExitFailure (-9)

This may be due to an out-of-memory condition.
```

So I googled some more and tried this command line: `cabal install --ghc-options="+RTS -M600M" -j1 cabal-install` from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46148345/52236

This seems to get further, but now I'm at this error:

```
ghc: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)  
(GHC version 8.6.5 for x86_64-unknown-linux):   heap overflow
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix this it would be appreciated. Do I need to add more RAM to my Docker Ubuntu image? It currently has 1.9GB of memory and 1.7GB free.
thanks,
m

Comment: The plutus lectures seem to require GHC 8.10 or above, so you probably have to get it from haskell.org instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @Li-yaoXia - I will try that when I'm trying to build the Plutus lectures code.

I worked around the heap overflow by updating the RTS param to -M1000M 

Now I'm stuck trying to update the symlink, because the cabal-install update wouldn't overwrite the existing one and installed to a different folder, so `cabal --version` on the terminal still says 2.4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by increasing the RTS param:

`cabal install --ghc-options="+RTS -M1000M" -j1 cabal-install`

Well, actually it compiled everything, but `cabal --version` still says 2.4, not 3.4. There was this warning too:

```
Warning: could not create a symlink in /root/.cabal/bin for cabal because the

file exists there already but is not managed by cabal. You can create a

symlink for this executable manually if you wish. The executable file has been

installed at /root/.cabal/bin/cabal
```